# IE gradient filter background overriding active background color

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I am styling a div that uses jQuery to add a `.active` class to the div when selected. The background of the div is a gradient, which I would like to keep. I am using the `filter:` property to display the gradient in IE. The active class modifies the background to a solid color, but in IE, the `filter:` CSS property overrides the `.active` styling.

Is there a solution to this, so the `.active` class will display the correct background color in IE?

See this example: http://jsbin.com/eDEjuzu/1/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `filter: none` to the `.active` class.  For IE6-9 gradients made with the `filter` property override normal `background` values, so you need to cancel out the gradient filter on `hover` in addition to changing the background color.

[Updated JSBin](http://jsbin.com/eDEjuzu/3/edit?html,output)

Comment: Yikes, I cant beleive I didn't think to set that to `filter: none`. Thanks for the extra info!

Comment: No problem! There is also an alternate gradient method for IE9 using SVGs instead of filters, which allows you to do multi step gradients.  I usually use Colorzilla's fantastic [Gradient Editor](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) for complex gradients and backwards compatibility.  Thank you for marking this the answer :)