# Mixing calc() and linear-gradient in multiple background not working in ie9

Tags: css

I want to reduce the usage of unnecessary div so I'm using multiple-background. But in ie9 it doesn't seems to work.

```
background: url(../images/home-2000.jpg) no-repeat -webkit-calc(50% - 200px) top, -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, #dfe2e7 50%, white 50%);
background: url(../images/home-2000.jpg) no-repeat calc(50% - 200px) top, linear-gradient(90deg, #dfe2e7 50%, white 50%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#dfe2e7', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=1 );
-webkit-background-size: auto 100%;
background-size: auto 100%;
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp says that gradients don't work with ie 9

Comment: if i only use linear-gradient and not have it in a multiple-background it does show the gradient though.

Answer (score 0):

IE9 doesn't support CSS gradients: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients

You can use this tool to add IE9 gradient support: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/
It creates an svg image that allows you to embed in the css.

Comment: well actually that's where the -webkit and filter style came from. it does work without the dat-image/svg if its not in the multiple-background.

Comment: Have you looked into this at all: http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/#pie-background. It generates an .htc file you include in the root of your site. Then you specify a line that accesses the .htc file: `behavior: url(path/to/PIE.htc)` and follow the documentation.

Comment: Also, according to this: http://www.briangervais.com/blog/css-gradients-with-internet-explorer-ie6-10, "IE9 will also use the MS filters generated for IE6-8 unless you specify otherwise." So filter is overriding background as is stated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168510/ie-gradient-filter-background-overriding-active-background-color